# Image downloaded from URL is blurry when in UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, nsurl

I downloaded an image from a URL using:

```
UIImage *someImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myImageURL]]];
UIImageView *someImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:someImage];
```

The image is sized for the iPad 3 so it is 1536 x 800 pixels. And when I download and display the image, it displays correctly, but on iPad 2 and iPad 3 it is very blurry and looks like I am scaling up a 768 x 400 pixel image.

How can I make this better resolution?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you are running on a retina display (use the scale property) and download a different image for both cases.

There is no point in using precious download time and volume to download huge images that will need to get down sampled later. It will give better user experience in every way.